# How to Enable UART in MT7620 Using Device Tree

Tags: embedded-linux, openwrt, device-tree

I have platform with **MT7620** in MIPS arch. On Platform is instaled OpenWRT. I also use Image Builder to create firmware. Now I whant to enable UART interface in my platform. I think that I must add inode to DT in **mt7620.dts** file but I do not know what must be the correct syntax. My propozition is below. I also need that UART worked as ttyS0 and console I whant to assigned to ttyS1 
So, in file mt7620.dts I whant to add this

```
    chosen {
             bootargs = "console=ttyS1,15200";
           };  

     uart@500 {
                    compatible = "ralink,mt7620a-uart", "ralink,rt2880-uart", "ns16550a";
                    reg = <0x500 0x100>;

                    interrupt-parent = <&intc>;
                    interrupts = <5>;

                    reg-shift = <2>;

                    pinctrl-names = "default";
                    pinctrl-0 = <&uartf_pins>;

                    status = "ok";
                };
```

Please tell me whether above syntax is correct ?

Main library (dtsi) its following inode UART

```
uart@500 {
    compatible = "ralink,mt7620a-uart", "ralink,rt2880-uart", "ns16550a";
    reg = <0x500 0x100>;

    resets = <&rstctrl 12>;
    reset-names = "uart";

    interrupt-parent = <&intc>;
    interrupts = <5>;

    reg-shift = <2>;

    status = "disabled";
};
```

**EITD**

The answer is simply. It should be add inode to `*.dts`

```
uart@500
{
    status = "okay"
}
```

That is all, because all parameters have been define in *.dtsi file.